# Why doesn't this XSS work?

Tags: xss

Possibly simple solution, but I can't understand why my attempt to run this alert script on my welcome page via XSS input on the index page doesn't work.

I have a simple index.htm page with a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="welcome.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the welcome.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h3> Welcome <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> </h3>

</body>
</html>
```

As a visitor to the index.php page, in the Name field I attempted to enter: 
    <script>alert("pwned")</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to deal with PHP itself, as most browsers has `XSS auditor` which will try to protect the user from know XSS attacks

Running your example would result in:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://localhost:9093/welcome.php' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server did not send an 'X-XSS-Protection' header.

For more information, you can check [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53474/is-chrome-completely-secure-against-reflected-xss)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm using method="post", not method="get" so I don't think it has anything to do with XSS auditor in my case.

Comment: @JSStuball read the answer to the linked question carefully , it states "when you put it in request URL or when HTML output returned by the server"

Comment: @niceman Haha I wish you wouldn't paraphrase, change the word 'and' to 'or' and then use quote marks.

Comment: @JSStuball sorry , my mistake

Comment: @JSStuball why would it make any difference if you're using get or post? the auditor is checking the source the browser received!

Comment: I think the article would be improved if this were made explicit.